# MONACAアプリ内部のHTMLへのアクセス

Tags: monaca, cordova

MONACAアプリでHTMLファイルをダウンロードして
（場所は`cdvfile://localhost/persistent/test.html`とします。）
上記のファイルをInAppBrowerで開きたいのですが、
アドレスをどのように設定すればよいのでしょうか？
ダウンロードしたファイル名（iFunBoxではmonaca/Documents）の一覧が表示されています
それをクリックすることでブラウザを開く予定です
function readFileで開く予定です

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <script src="components/loader.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="components/loader.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <script>
      var directoryEntry;

  document.addEventListener('deviceready', init, false);
  function init() {
  //window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.TEMPORARY, 0, getFilesFromDirectory, fail);
   window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, getFilesFromDirectory, fail);
  document.getElementById('download').addEventListener('click', downloadFile, false);
  }

  function getFilesFromDirectory(fileSystem) {
  //directoryEntry =cordova.file.documentsDirectory;
  //directoryEntry = 'cdvfile://localhost/persistent/path/to/';
  directoryEntry = 'cdvfile://localhost/persistent/';

  //directoryEntry2 = '/path/to/';
  directoryEntry2 =fileSystem.root;
  //alert(directoryEntry2);
  var directoryReader = directoryEntry2.createReader();
  directoryReader.readEntries(putFileName, fail);
  //window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.TEMPORARY, 0, getFilesFromDirectory, fail);
  }

  function putFileName(entries) {
      //alert(entries.length);
  for ( index = 0; index < entries.length; index++ ) {
      //alert(entries[index].fullPath);
  if ( entries[index].isFile ) {
  var listItem = document.createElement('li');
  listItem.textContent = entries[index].name;
  listItem.title = entries[index].fullPath; 
 //listItem.addEventListener('click', uploadFile, false);
  listItem.addEventListener('click', viewFile, false);
  document.getElementById('fileList').appendChild(listItem);
  }
  }
  }

  function downloadFile() {
  // FileTransferオブジェクトを作成
  var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();

  // ダウンロード先のURIをencodeURIでエンコード

  //alert(cordova.file.applicationDirectory);
  var uri = encodeURI('http://image.gihyo.co.jp/assets/templates/gihyojp2007/image/gihyojp_logo.png');
  //alert(uri);
  // 保存するファイルの名前
  //alert(time);
  var fileName = 'gihyojp_logo2.png';

  // 保存先をフルパスで指定

  //var path = directoryEntry.fullPath + '/' + fileName ;
  //var path = cordova.file.documentsDirectory  + fileName ;
  var path = directoryEntry + fileName;
  //var path = directoryEntry;
  //var path = 'cdvfile://localhost/persistent/path/to/' + fileName;
  //alert(path);
  // ファイルのダウンロードを実行
  fileTransfer.download(uri, path, downloadSuccess, downloadFail);
  }

  function downloadSuccess(fileEntry) {
  alert('ファイルを' + fileEntry.fullPath + 'に保存しました。');
  location.reload();
  }

  function downloadFail(fileTransferError) {
    var error = '';

    switch(fileTransferError.code) {
        case FileTransferError.FILE_NOT_FOUND_ERR:
        error = '第2引数にファイルURLが指定されていません';
        //error = '第2引数にファイルURLが指定されていません URI=[' + uri + '] PATH=[' + path + ']' ;
        break;
        case FileTransferError.INVALID_URL_ERR:
        error = '不正なファイルパスが第2引数で指定されています';
        break;
        case FileTransferError.CONNECTION_ERR:
        error = '接続エラー';
        break;
        default: 
        error = '未定義のエラー';
        break;
    }

  alert(error + '\nhttp_status: ' + fileTransferError.http_status);
  }

  function viewFile(event) {
  //alert("viewFile");
  directoryEntry2.getFile(event.target.textContent, null ,getFile,fail);
  }
  function getFile(fileEntry){
      //alert("getFile");
  fileEntry.file(readFile,fail);
  }
  function readFile(file){
      //表示部分
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    var fname=file.name;
    reader.onloadend = function(event){
        if(fname.match(/html$/i)){
            window.open(monaca.baseUrl+fname, "_system", "");
        }else{
            var img= new Image();
            img.src = event.target.result;
            img.onload = function(){
            document.getElementById("view").src=img.src;
            }
        }
    }
  }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="app">
        <h1>File API Test</h1>
        <p>
        <input id="download" type="button" value="download gihyo logo">
        </p>
        <ul id="fileList"></ul>
        <img id="view" src="" >

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
window.open(entry.toURL(), '_blank', 'location=no');
```

entry.toURL()については、下記ドキュメントにあります。
http://docs.monaca.mobi/3.5/ja/reference/phonegap_34/ja/file/plugins/